# Map method in python

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

```
class FoodExpert:
    def init(self):
        self.goodFood = []
    def addGoodFood(self, food):
        self.goodFood.append(food)
    def likes(self, x):
        return x in self.goodFood
    def prefers(self, x, y):
        x_rating = self.goodFood.index(x)
        y_rating = self.goodFood.index(y)
        if x_rating > y_rating:
            return y
        else:
            return x
```

After declaring this class , I wrote this code :

```
>>> f = FoodExpert()
>>> f.init()
>>> map(f.addGoodFood, ['SPAM', 'Eggs', 'Bacon', 'Rat', 'Spring Surprise'])
[None, None, None, None, None]

>>> f.goodFood
['SPAM', 'Eggs', 'Bacon', 'Rat', 'Spring Surprise']
```

I am unable to understand how the map function is working behind the hood , why is it returning a list with all `None` , but when I check `f.goodFood` the elements have been added there ?

Comment: Note that using `map` like this is a bad idea. Use a `for` loop; it won't create a list, and it'll work in Python 3 without needing you to wrap it in a `list` call.

Comment: (Were you expecting the `map` call to return `f.goodFood`? It doesn't. It doesn't even know `f.goodFood` is relevant.)

Comment: For this usage you'd be better off doing `f.goodFood.extend(["spam", "eggs", etc])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map` applies a function on an iterable and returns a new list where the function was applied on each item.

In your case, it shows `None` because `f.addGoodFood` function returns nothing.

For testing purposes change `addGoodFood` this way:

```
def addGoodFood(self, food):
    self.goodFood.append(food)
    return "test"
```

and see:

```
>>> map(f.addGoodFood, ['SPAM', 'Eggs', 'Bacon', 'Rat', 'Spring Surprise'])
['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```

Comment: Why do we actually need  map func? we can still add values to the the goodFood list. Is there any good reason or some scenario for using map.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `addGoodFood` isn't returning anything.  Make it return something:

```
def addGoodFood(self, food):
    self.goodFood.append(food)
    return food
```

`map` is creating a list of the *results* of calling `addGoodFood` on each item in the list.  And, since the `append` method of a list always returns `None`, you get a list of `None`'s.

Also, you might want to change your `init` function to this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.goodFood = []
```

`__init__` is a special method that handles the initialization of a class.  Using it means that you don't have to do `f.init()`.

Answer (score 4):

`result = map(function, iterable)` is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for item in iterable:
    result.append(function(item))
```

So internally it builds a list in which it appends the result of applying the function on every item in the list.

Since your function `addGoodFood` returns nothing, the `map` function return a list of `None`s.

Your function has a side effect to append it's items to the `goodFoods` list, the `goodFoods` list gets populated and has all the elements. But since, as I said, function returns nothing map returned a list that is the same size as the original list (since it is applied on every element) full of `None`s.

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question is returning a list with `None` elements because `addGoodFood()` doesn't *explicitly* return anything (implicitly, it'll return `None`). `map()` collects the *results* of the function that you call, and creates a new list with those results.

You should not use `map()` with a function that doesn't return a value. In this case, `addGoodFood()` is *not* a good candidate for using it. This is is how you should write it:

```
for food in ['SPAM', 'Eggs', 'Bacon', 'Rat', 'Spring Surprise']:
    f.addGoodFood(food)
```

To answer the question: how does `map()` work under the hood? here's how:

```
def map(func, lst):
    result = []
    for e in lst:
        result.append(func(e))
    return result
```

In the above function it's obvious why you're getting a list of `None` elements as a result: if the passed function returns `None`, then the loop will execute `result.append(None)`, and the returned list will only contain `None` in each position.

Comment: I understand what are you saying , I am learning python from a book , I implemented this code from there , that is why I was also confused !

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't return anything from `addGoodFood` function.